# Migrating PHP sites from 32 bit RedHat to 64 bit

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, 32bit-64bit

I have all my sites in PHP/MySql some are running on Drupal. We need to migrate to a 64 bit box because we need much more RAM. 
Will I have  any problems with the websites after the move?

thanks

Comment: In short: No. In long (because I must write at least 15 characters): What do you expect? You may try it first in a virtual machine, if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are relying on software / plugins / extensions other than Apache, PHP and MySQL (all of which have transparent and stable x64 implementations), then no.

Note that you need not be concerned with what PHP applications you are using (e.g. Drupal) as they interface with PHP.  Rather you should be concerned with what extensions or plugins you are using (e.g. ImageMagick, PEAR, etc.).

But unless you are using something wild, your migration will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may have problems, but not because of 32/64 bits version of PHP, but because of the following:

- Server settings in php.ini - For example if you upload files, the default max size is very small (1 or 2Mb), check your settings in your current php.ini and copy them when necessary.
- Different version of PHP. I suppose the new server could have a newer version of PHP, and since PHP has all the functions in the global namespaces, newly introduced functions may cause problems when clashing with user defined functions.
- Required extensions. Make sure that all extensions that you need are loaded, you can check them with phpinfo().